# Start/Assign macOS app with root privileges

Tags: xcode, root, sudo, nsapplescript

I have written a macOS Cocoa app using XCode 9.2.

The purpose of the app is as a wrapper to a set of shell commands so that users can run commands easily as required. The shell script allow the users to control a particular device driver for which the software is written by another party.

I have managed to get the app to invoke the shell command as root.

But there are some sub-commands that fail. The actual commands run are, and I think it is the 2nd "`stop -a`" that fails:

```
do shell script \"
cd '/Library/Application Support/ABC' ;
 python '/Library/Application Support/ABC/abc.py' stop -d;
 python  '/Library/Application Support/ABC/abc.py' stop -a;
 python '/Library/Application Support/ABC/abc.py' stop -g;
 python '/Library/Application Support/ABC/abc.py' stop -t;\"
 with administrator privileges
```

When I run the same commands in Terminal they work, either as discrete commands or in a shell script.

As a last resort I ran the app from the command line using

```
sudo ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname/Build/Products/Debug/appname.app/Contents/MacOS/appname
```

And this works perfectly.

So, it seems that when I run using the NSAppleScript framework, which correctly prompts me for the root password, there is still something amiss which causes the command failure. But when the whole app runs under `sudo` everything works.

So the solution appears to be to set the app to require Root privs. Is there a setting that can be set for the built project that would automatically set this such that the root password is requested on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working in that I do not get the error, but would still like some pointers on how to set an app to run as admin.